# Am i able to use client's certificate in iPhone

Tags: iphone, certificate, provisioning, keychain

I'm iphone developer and have a client.
One day he wants to update uploaded live app in App Store and give me source code, his apple id and password.
I entered iOS Provisioning Portal by using his apple id.
there was already one distribution certificate and i downloaded it (distribution_identity.cer) and provisioning file (xxx.mobileprovision).
I setup provisioning file, but i got a error "iPhone App Signing: A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain".
so I setup distribution_identity.cer file but still got the error.
I think I need the p12 file for distribution certificate.
can i make the p12 file?
or do I need the p12 file to client?
I'm not working out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need the .pi2 file from the client.

The other method is , revoke the certificate  from the portal and regenerate it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks. But if i revoke the certificate, can i use distribution provision for the uploaded app?

Answer (score 0):

You need the p12, and you might also want to create a separate User account on your Mac for using it so that the XCode doesn't get confused by having multiple Developer certificates in the current account's Keychain.